# Embed youtube inside one_half shortcode

Tags: wordpress, youtube, shortcode

I am embedding a YouTube video inside a "one_half" shortcode but it is not working for some reason. I am hoping maybe someone could help me out. (one_half shortcut just wraps the element in a div that is set to be 50% in width, see below).

Here is my shortcode code:

```
function one_half_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
    return '<div class="one_half">' . do_shortcode($content) . '</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'one_half', 'one_half_shortcode' );
```

And here is what I am adding into the editor:

```
[one_half]https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ya17jbkOKDk[/one_half]
```

Also tried:

```
[one_half][youtube=https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ya17jbkOKDk][/one_half]
```

Not working, just shows the URL right on the page instead of rendering the video.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, figured it out.

The trick is to put the YouTube call on it's own line. Like this:

```
[one_half]
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ya17jbkOKDk
[/one_half]
```